# SWIFT 4: cellForRowAt skipping last row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array of coins with 14 elements and I am using the coins.count as the return value of the function 'numberOfRowsInSection'

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.coins.count
    }
```

but the function that return the cell is only running 13 times (until index 12)

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let celula = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellCoin", for: indexPath) as! CoinTableViewCell
            print("row " + String(indexPath.row))
            let coin = coins[indexPath.row]
            investment = coin.value(forKey: "investment") as! Double
            viewTotalInvestment += investment
```

at the same time that I am creating the cell, it goes to the API endpoint to check the coin value, but I don't think that it could be the problem

any suggestion about what can be happening?

Comment: Is there room on the screen for the last row? Only visible rows are loaded.

Comment: Are you sure that the array contains 14 items? I suspect it's a `...` vs. `..<` together with `count` vs. `count - 1` or another misleading zero-based index mistake while populating the array.

Comment: I tried return coins.count + 1.. but coins[indexPath.row] gets an index out of bounds. I can see only 3 or 3 and half cells on the visible screen, but it loads 12... if I scroll down, it loads the 13 one... but if I scroll back again to the first coin, my "sum of totals" doesn't counts the coin number 13 again

Comment: No, returning `self.coins.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection ` is perfect. How is `sum of totals` defined? Are you gathering data directly form the cell? If yes don't do that.

Comment: I edited the question.. check the investment, is just a += calculation... but since it goes just until coin 12, the value of coin 13 is never counting, just if I scroll down to it

Comment: `cellForRowAt` is for loading cell data to be displayed. Nothing else. If you want the sum of your coin values, then sum up the values directly.

Comment: when the table loads a cell, it also goes to the API to get its current value. I need this value to calculate my profits, that is why I was calculating everything together. The actual value of the 13 coin is not being load until I roll the table down. I wish I could check all the values without have to scroll the table

Comment: initiate a background thread (serial queue ) to do that task without scrolling

Answer (score 2):

I want to be very clear here. The whole `UITableViewDataSource` protocol is for displaying table view data only. Do not use it for any other display purposes and ***NEVER*** use it for data processing.

If you want to calculate `viewTotalInvestment`, then define it like this

```
var viewTotalInvestment: Double {
    var result = 0.0
    for coin in coins {
        let investment = coin.value(forKey: "investment") as! Double
        result = result + investment
    }
    return result
}
```

or even better as

```
var viewTotalInvestment: Double {
    return coins.reduce(0.0) { result, coin in
        let investment = coin.value(forKey: "investment") as! Double
        return result + investment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CellForRowAt** is called to display only cells that are visible If you scrolled to the end of the table you may find print message in console for the last row (13) if it's really exists in the array and that's is the key behind dequeuing . . .

Comment: I can see only 3 or 3 and half cells on the visible screen, but it loads 12 at the first time... if I scroll down, it loads the 13 one... but if I scroll back again to the first coin, my "sum of totals" doesn't counts the coin number 13 again. It is strange, why 12 but not 13 even if I can only se 3 or 4 coins on screen?

Comment: when you get the array from the api log it's count before reloading the table

Comment: my array is predeterminated, I dont have to go to api to get it, just the values of the coins